# How to Handle if condition with multiple statement in windows batch without goto or call

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

How can I handle an windows batch if condition with multiple statement without using `goto` or `call` function -

```
If (%value1%=="Test") (
statement1
statement2
statement3
statement4
)

else (
statement1
statement2
statement3
statement4
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use folowing statement:

```
if %value1%=="Test" ( 
  statement1 
  statement2
  statement3
  statement4
) else ( 
  statement1
  statement2 
  statement3
  statement4 
)
```

Comment: correct. Just to add an explanation: the trick is: `if a==b command1 else command2` has to be a single line. With parantheses you can split a single logical line to several physical lines, but `) else (` has to be on the same physical line to not break the logical line. It's even described in `if /?`